# Validate This EF4 Validation Approach?

Tags: c#, validation, entity-framework-4, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I'm *very* new to EF4. I've posted a couple of times I think regarding inheritance, validation but my overall aim is to reduce the amount of code I write as much as possible. I'm not interested (yet) in POCOs, masses of ObjectContext fiddling: I want the benefit of EF and minimum of coding.

So, the thorny issue of validation. Take a look at this simplified example and (aside from DRY Buddies and dodgy usings aliases), is this looking like a half-decent approach?

```
namespace Model
{
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;
    using DataAnnotations = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Validation = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;

    [HasSelfValidation]
    [DataAnnotations.MetadataType(typeof(PersonValidator))]
    public partial class Person
    {
        [SelfValidation]
        public Validation.ValidationResults Validate()
        {
            var validationResults = Validation.Validation.Validate(this);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName) || this.LastName.Length > 4)
            {
                validationResults.AddResult(new Validation.ValidationResult("This is a test error message for a custom validation error.", this, null, null, null));
            }

            return validationResults;
        }
    }

    [HasSelfValidation]
    public class PersonValidator
    {
        [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "First Name must be supplied.")]
        [ContainsCharactersValidator("Rcd", ContainsCharacters.All, MessageTemplate = "{1} must contains characters \"{3}\" ({4}).")]
        [StringLengthValidator(5, 50, MessageTemplate = "{1} (\"{0}\") must be between {3} ({4}) and {5} ({6}) characters in length.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "Last Name must be supplied.")]
        [ContainsCharactersValidator("Wes", ContainsCharacters.All, MessageTemplate = "{1} must contains characters \"{3}\" ({4}).")]
        [StringLengthValidator(5, 50, MessageTemplate = "{1} (\"{0}\") must be between {3} ({4}) and {5} ({6}) characters in length.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There's something rather cool about this. I can call the above like this:

```
var validationResults = person.Validate();
```

BUT, if I just want some basic checking, I can strip out Validate(), the [SelfValidation] stuff, keep the attributes and then just call:

```
var validationResults = Validation.Validate(person);
```

I only need to include as much validation as I need and there's ZERO configuration in web.config.

How's the cut of my jib? :)

Richard

Comment: personally, i don't think you should validate in your model for things like "length of lastname". That is validation of *input*, which should be done in the presentation tier. Last-minute validation should be done by EF itself which will validate the fields against the underlying database constraints (e.g `NVARCHAR(4)` - which prevents anything > 4 characters). at what point in your application would you call `person.Validate`?

Comment: Like I said, a simple example. Imagine it in the context of a real world app with real world validation that would take too long to code up as an example.

Comment: I guess (again simply!) call like:using (var context = new ModelContainer()) { var person = new Person(); var validationResults = Validation.Validate(person); if (validationResults.IsValid) { context.AddToPeople(person); } else { WriteValidationResults(validationResults); }} but that EF stuff is still new to me, so...

Comment: CTP 5 has DataAnnotations validation built in. Can you wait?

Comment: I recently noticed the built in support CTP 5 has for DataAnnotations BUT seems code-only at this point? I want model / database first. Typical :) For now, I'm going with the answer below and I gues it'll be happy refactoring time in 6 months or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm personally not a fan of calling validation directly in code, and especially not directly on a entity itself. There will be a lot of places were you will call `Validate` and it is easy to forget to call `Validate`. Instead, let the `ObjectContext` invoke the underlying validation framework automatically for ALL entities that have changed, and throw a special exception (that can be caught in the presentation layer) when validation errors occur.

You can do this by hooking onto the `ObjectContext.SavingChanges` event and trigger validation there. You can write your partial `ObjectContext` as follows:

```
public partial class ModelContainer
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.SavingChanges +=
            (sender, e) => Validate(this.GetChangedEntities());
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> GetChangedEntities()
    {
        const EntityState AddedAndModified =
            EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified;

        var entries = this.ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(AddedAndModified);

        return entries.Where(e => e != null);
    }

    private static void Validate(IEnumerable<object> entities)
    {
        ValidationResults[] invalidResults = (
            from entity in entities
            let type = entity.GetType()
            let validator = ValidationFactory.CreateValidator(type)
            let results = validator.Validate(entity)
            where !results.IsValid
            select results).ToArray();

        if (invalidResults.Length > 0)
            throw new ValidationException(invalidResults);
    }    
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=46).

Comment: I know it's a bit old. But this is a very nice approach +1